# file download using mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, web-applications, download

I am creating PHP page that allows users to download files when they click in this button:

```
<td><a href='download.php?id={$row['file_name']}'>Download</a></td>
```

then the page redirect to download.php, code:

```
<?php
  // Make sure an ID was passed
    if(isset($_GET['file_name'])) {
        // Get the ID$id
        $file_name= ($_GET['file_name']);
        // Make sure the ID is in fact a valid ID
    if($file_name == NULL) {
        die('The name is invalid!');
    }
    else {
        // Connect to the database
        $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', "", 'db_name');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
        }
         // Fetch the file information
        $query = "
            SELECT `type`, `file_name`, `size`, `data`
            FROM `pdfs`
            WHERE `file_name` = {$file_name}";
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);

        if($result) {
            // Make sure the result is valid
            if($result->num_rows == 1) {
            // Get the row
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                header("Content-Type: ".$row['type']);
                header("Content-Length: ".$row['size']);
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment"); 
                // disopsition = attachment to force download request
                // Print data
                echo $row['data'];
            }
            else {
                echo 'Error! No file exists with that ID.';
            }
            // Free the mysqli resources
            @mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
            // if there is an error excuting the query
            echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }
        // close database connection
        @mysqli_close($dbLink);
    }
}
else {
    // if no ID passed
    echo 'Error! No ID was passed.';
}
?>
```

however, wehn i click in download i always get the massage of the last else statement "error no id was passed", but i can't find the problem, is the problem that i made the primary key of the file is the name??

Comment: Here be SQL injection vulnerabilities. The 'No ID was passed' message seems to be fired when no file_name supplied - but the way the code is structured it's very hard to read. That would explain why your link is causing an error

Answer (score 2):

If your link looks like this:

```
<a href='download.php?id={$row['file_name']}'>
```

Then the `GET` variable will be 'id' as in `$_GET['id']` and *not* `$_GET['file_name']`

Answer (score 2):

```
$_GET['file_name'] should be $_GET['id']

since <a href='download.php?id={$row['file_name']}'> you sending "id" not "file_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Typo**

```
<td><a href='download.php?id=<?php echo $row['file_name']; ?>'>Download</a></td>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href='download.php?id={$row['file_name']}'>
```

u should use `<a href="download.php?id=<?= $row['file_name'];?>">`

then use `$_GET['id']` since id is the variable u pass in url not `$_GET['file_name']`